# How to finish the forever statement on run_phase in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand `forever` statement in `raise_objection()/drop_objection()`.
I thought that the `forever` statement will be finished after `drop_objection()`. But, the below `forever` statement does not finish.

```
    forever begin
        q_trans_addr.push_back(trans.addr);
    end
```

So the simulation be hanged. It couldn't finish. What am I supposed to do to finish if I want to use `forever` statement in `run_phase()`?

```
class component_b extends uvm_component;
    transaction trans;
    int m_num_rx;
    logic [31:0] q_trans_addr[$];
    uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo#(transaction) m_analysis_fifo;
    `uvm_component_utils(component_b)
    
    function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
        super.new(name, parent);
        m_analysis_fifo = new("m_analysis_fifo",this);
    endfunction
    
    virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
        phase.raise_objection(this);
        repeat(m_num_rx) begin
            #300;
            `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf(" COMPB Before calling analysis fifo get method"), UVM_LOW)
            m_analysis_fifo.get(trans);
        end
        forever begin
            q_trans_addr.push_back(trans.addr);
        end
        phase.drop_objection(this);
    endtask
endclass
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense so it is unclear what functionality you are looking for. The repeat loop would just overwrite each trans you are getting. Maybe you just need to move the `q_trans_addr.push_back(trans.addr);` as the last statement of the repeat loop, and remove the forever loop. You need to explain how it is supposed to operate before anyone could show you how to fix it.

Comment: @dave_59 That's why I used m_analysis_fifo.get(trans); to prevent overwrite when I am getting.  I understand that uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo is working as FIFO, why does The repeat loop would just overwrite trans? How to avoid the overwrite from it? Could you please guide me ?

Comment: What kind of component is this? a scoreboard? what is put()ing into the analysis fifo, a monitor? and how are the put()s timed? what does #300 represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forever` block will never end.  This means that you will never exit the block and never execute the `drop_objection` statement.  Therefore, your test hangs.

Objections are not typically used in **components**; they are typically used in **tests** (classes extended from `uvm_test`).  Remove the objection statements from your `run_phase` code:

```
virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    repeat(m_num_rx) begin
        #300;
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf(" COMPB Before calling analysis fifo get method"), UVM_LOW)
        m_analysis_fifo.get(trans);
    end
    forever begin
        q_trans_addr.push_back(trans.addr);
    end
endtask
```

---

However, that `forever` block is a zero-time infinite loop, which may still cause your simulation to hang.  You would normally have some other statement in the block, like a `wait` or a delay.